# Is it possible for an Adobe AIR app to receive touch events in OS X?

Tags: macos, events, air, multi-touch

I'm working on software in OS X that receives touches from a multi-touch device and posts them to the system for applications to process.  I was hoping that it would be possible to support Adobe AIR applications, but from the research I've done, it looks like they don't support multi-touch events on OS X. [This page](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/multitouch_gestures.html) in particular seems to indicate that, and consistent with what it says, the AIR applications I've tested with do indeed only respond to gesture events, but not touch events.  However I'm (perhaps naively) hoping there's a way to do it regardless.

So is it possible for an AIR application running in Mac OS X to receive touch events at all?  Perhaps using a different method than posting system-wide touch events?  For example, is there any way my software could somehow send touch events directly to an AIR app?

Thanks in advance!